# SQL Compare Rows With Duplicate IDs and Return One With Lowest Sequence Number

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Reaching out for help. I've seen plenty of answers on how to use DUPLICATE, but not quite how I need it. Let's say I have the result of query that looks like the following.

[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ7TQ.png)

```
  Incident_No   Open_Approval_Step      Approval_ID     
 ------------- -------------------- ------------------- 
            1                    3   Tech               
            1                    4   Cust_Serv          
            2                    1   Incident_Recorder  
            2                    2   Estimation         
            2                    3   Tech               
            3                    4   Cust_Serv          
            3                    5   Mgmt               
            3                    6   Closure
```

And I need one row for each incident number with the smallest numbered approval step. So the result should look like this.

[filtered query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUTqB.png)

```
  Incident_No   Open_Approval_Step      Approval_ID     
 ------------- -------------------- ------------------- 
            1                    3   Tech               
            2                    1   Incident_Recorder  
            3                    4   Cust_Serv
```

*Edit* This is what I came up with in the end

```
SELECT DISTINCT

MIN(OPEN_APPROVAL_STEP) OVER(PARTITION BY INCIDENT_NO ORDER BY OPEN_APPROVAL_STEP ASC) AS CUR_APP_STEP,

INCIDENT_NO

FROM T
```

Comment: I played around with this a bit more based on what @GMB suggested below. It was a great step in logic that pushed me in the right direction. This seems like a somewhat more straightforward solution I came around to.

SELECT DISTINCT
MIN(OPEN_APPROVAL_STEP) OVER(PARTITION BY INCIDENT_NO ORDER BY OPEN_APPROVAL_STEP ASC) AS CUR_APP_STEP,
INCIDENT_NO

FROM T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by incident_no order by open_approval_step) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

With just one extra column appart from the incident number and approval step, another option is aggregation and Oracle's `keep` syntax:

```
select 
    incident_no,
    min(open_approval_step) open_approval_step,
    min(approval_id) keep(dense_rank first order by open_approval_step) approval_id
from mytable
group by incident_no
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can get the row numbers to add up when I put the row_number function under my main select function. Once I add it in a nested select function so I can call the rn = 1 where clause, it breaks down. Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: @RickityRick: I can't tell without seeing your actual query (which you did not initially shared). The simplest option is to replace `from mytable t` in my query with `from (... you query here ...) t` (although neatest options are probably possible).

Comment: I understand that I did not share my initial query and that makes it more difficult to troubleshoot. Unfortunately, I can't due to proprietary information. I think that I know where I went wrong with nesting the query. Since I know the row_number is functioning properly, I should be able to get it from there. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just three columns, you can easily use aggregation:

```
select incident_no, min(open_approval_step),
       min(approval_id) keep (dense_rank first order by open_approval_step) 
from t
group by incident_no;
```

Comment: I have several other columns that are in this table. Does aggregation break down with 3+? I'm just learning SQL.

Comment: @RickityRick . . . You can add more expressions such as the `keep` expression in this example.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I'll need to dig around for some more information on the keep function. Just some cursory searches on the Oracle site yields little information. I'm definitely intrigued to learn more!